# library not found for -lopencv_highgui.2.4.9

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, hyperlink

I was following [this](http://tilomitra.com/opencv-on-mac-osx/) to make my first OpenCV project, showing a picture with imshow() function.

I right clicked on the project and clicked "Add files to..", added libopencv_core.2.4.9.dylib and libopencv_highgui.2.4.9.dylib. Then I added "/usr/local/include" in "Header Search Paths".

However, I met this error: "ld: library not found for -lopencv_highgui.2.4.9".

But if I added "/usr/local/lib" in "Library Search Paths", it worked!

My question is: since I already added libraries in the project, why do I bother to added "/usr/local/lib"?

p.s. I am using Xcode5.1.1 and OpenCV2.4.9

Comment: Thanks, your question helped me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only added the library name itself. The linker does not know, where to search it. The linker has some default search paths built in (e.g. `/lib` or `/usr/lib`), but `/usr/local/lib` is not one of it. [Historically the local path has to store local software only.](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-4.9.html) `/usr` could be stored on a network mount. Thus there could be other rights management on `/usr/local` and thus it may be a security problem, if `ld` would automatically search in this subdirectories per default.